# How to express this to a child: "It is good that you inform me in advance before you pee so I can put you to the bathroom..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, phrase-request, sentence-usage

Now, you don't want to put a diaper on your child because it may cause diaper rash. Thus, you just let him wear normal clothes.

But your child may pee his pants without telling you in advance. If that happened, you had to clean up his pee, which was tiring.

But one day, he informed you in advance so that you could "**put him into the bathroom**" (**Note:** I am not sure we can say like that the same way we use the idiom "**to put a child to bed**")".

Then **how would I express that to him?**

Is it ok to say "**It is good that you inform me in advance before you pee so I can put you to the bathroom and you won't pee your pants anymore**"?

Comment: 'Inform me in advance' sounds amusingly formal! I don't have much experience of small children, but I expect you would say something like 'Tell me when you need a wee/pee so that I can take you to the toilet/bathroom in time.'

Comment: @KateBunting, that is elegant. I like it.